# What is the fastest method of finding a file in Linux and Windows using Python?

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am writing a plug-in for RawTherapee in Python. I need to extract the version number from a file called 'AboutThisBuild.txt' that may exist anywhere in the directory tree. Although RawTherapee knows where it is installed this data is baked into the binary file.

My plug-in is being designed to collect basic system data when run without any command line parameters for the purpose of short circuiting troubleshooting. By having the version number, revision number and changeset (AKA Mercurial), I can sort out why the script may not be working as expected. OK that is the context.

I have tried a variety of methods, some suggested elsewhere on this site. The main one is using os.walk and fnmatch.

The problem is speed. Searching the entire directory tree is like watching paint dry!

To reduce load I have tried to predict likely hiding places and only traverse these. This is quicker but has the obvious disadvantage of missing some files.

This is what I have at the moment. Tested on Linux but not Windows as yet as I am still researching where the file might be placed.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys

rootPath = ('/usr/share/doc/rawtherapee',
            '~',
            '/media/CoreData/opt/',
            '/opt')
pattern = 'AboutThisBuild.txt'

# Return the first instance of RT found in the paths searched
for CheckPath in rootPath:
    print("\n")
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>> " + CheckPath)
    print("\n")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CheckPath, True, None, False):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            print( os.path.join(root, filename))
            break
```

Usually 'AboutThisBuild.txt' is stored in a directory/subdirectory called 'rawtherapee' or has the string somewhere in the directory tree. I had naively though I could get the 5000 odd directory names and search these for 'rawtherapee' then use os.walk to traverse those directories but all modules and functions I have looked at collate all files in the directory (again).

Anyone have a quicker method of searching the entire directory tree or am I stuck with this hybrid option?

Comment: Umm, why not use `find`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, `find` is still a brute force solution.

Comment: True, but it would be faster - I think the OP is looking for speed rather than finesse.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, find is not really cross-platform. I need something that can be easily used on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about searching is that it doesn't matter too much how you get there (eg cheating). Once you have a result, you can verify it is correct relatively quickly.

You may be able to identify candidate locations fairly efficiently by guessing. For example, on Linux, you could first try looking in these locations (obviously not all are directories, but it doesn't do any harm to `os.path.isfile('/;l$/AboutThisBuild.txt')`)

```
$ strings /usr/bin/rawtherapee | grep '^/'
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
/H=!
/;l$
/9T$,
/.ba
/usr/share/rawtherapee
/usr/share/doc/rawtherapee
/themes/
/themes/slim
/options
/usr/share/color/icc
/cache
/languages/default
/languages/
/languages
/themes
/batch/queue
/batch/
/dcpprofiles
/@q=
/N6rtexif16NAISOInterpreterE
```

If you have it installed, you can try the `locate` command

If you still don't find it, move on to the brute force method

Here is a rough equivalent of `strings` using Python

```
>>> from string import printable, whitespace
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> pathchars = set(printable) - set(whitespace)
>>> with open("/usr/bin/rawtherapee") as fp:
...     data = fp.read()
... 
>>> for k, g in groupby(data, pathchars.__contains__):
...     if not k: continue
...     g = ''.join(g)
...     if len(g) > 3 and g.startswith("/"):
...         print g
... 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/^W0Kq[
/pW$<
/3R8
/)wyX
/WUO
/w=H
/t_1
/.badpixH
/d$(
/\$P
/D$Pv
/D$@
/D$(
/l$@
/d$@v?H
/usr/share/rawtherapee
/usr/share/doc/rawtherapee
/themes/
/themes/slim
/options
/usr/share/color/icc
/cache
/languages/default
/languages/
/languages
/themes
/batch/queue.csv
/batch/
/dcpprofiles
/@q=
/N6rtexif16NAISOInterpreterE
```

Comment: The code I showed above works on this premise. Guess the most likely directory then drill down; the problem is the number of builds available. You can't assume that the build will always put the stuff in the same place. I have asked the RawTherapee community to indicate the place where their version resides but only a few have replied - [link](http://rawtherapee.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4796).

Comment: @SimonCropper, I wasn't suggesting you just use this list. I'm suggesting you search for strings that look like paths in the specific binary you are interested in. It's easy enough to do this in a Python script.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. To be thorough, you should allow for unicode in the paths etc. but then you'll end up with a _lot_ more candidates.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it best reflects a workable solution. In reality it is a more detailed expansion of the method I originally posted but gnibbler proposed one great idea that i intend to implement -- extract the paths from published builds and use these in my primary search.

Comment: My original question "What is the fastest method of finding a file in Linux and Windows using Python?" is in reality still open. Once the primary search is complete falling back to searching the entire filesystem is unrealistic as it just takes too long. I think I will just state "unable to be determined" in my log and push the obligation of determining the RT version to the user.

Comment: @SimonCropper, If tricks like this don't work, then unless you have a searchable index I don't see how you could do it without scanning the whole filesystem. The compiled-in directory will very likely show up in the binary _somewhere_. Other options might be to try to analyse the binary or run via some sort of wrapper (`strace`?) to catch the file system calls.

Comment: First, RT is Open Source so if I can get my head around C++ I could see where the defaults are pointing. The thing is though that you can obviously point things to different places for different builds, so it opens up a variety of alternative locations. The people installing the program also have the option to choose where they would like to put the file.

Comment: Next, assuming the application is installed in the "normal" areas I thought that you could query a database of some sort- a bit like the 'updatedb' accessed by **mlocate** on Ubuntu ([link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-April/533285.html)). Most modern file systems should have an index of files - I doubt they would search the directory tree every time they want a file! Again, I also presumed that Python would have a standard module or even a third party module that could access commonly encountered file systems. To date, I have not found much except the Linux example above

Comment: ...and the Linux example quoted was only just found because I was trying to provide and example to gnibbler of an index database similar to what I expected an ext2, ext3, FAT32 or NTFS would have; and I was aware that **locate** command on Linux used an indexed file while **find** actually traverses the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner in Python, but I think I know the simplest way of finding a file in Windows.

```
import os
for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk('The directory you wanna search the file in'):
    if 'name of your file with extension' in filenames:
        print(dirpath)
```

This code will print out the directory of the file you are searching for in the console. All you have to do is get to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a pure python solution here. If not, other answers will suffice.

In this case, you should traverse the folders using a queue and threads. While some may say Threads are never the solution, Threads are a great way of speeding up when you are I/O bound, which you are in this case. Essentially, you'll os.listdir the current dir. If it contains your file, party like it's 1999. If it doesn't, add each subfolder to the work queue.

If you're clever, you can play with [depth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) vs [breadth first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) traversal to get the best results.

There is a great example I have used quite successfully at work at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm. See the section titled `Multithreaded Priority Queue`. The example could probably be updated to include threadpools though, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Threads are a terrible idea if it means you're going to be seeking (thrashing) all over your (mechanical) hard drive. If it's an SSD a few threads may help

Comment: @VooDooNOFX, Yes I do need a pure Python solution. Something truly cross-platform and works in Python 2.7 and 3.0. Multithreading does sound interesting but as gnibbler said would result in 2 or 3 processes fighting for control of the HD resulting in potentially erratic seeks throughout media. This could result in the script taking longer than working through the tree systematically with a single process.